# When I was teaching absolute function properties, I suddenly made this question ...

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value, education

I was teaching absolute function properties in a [K-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9312) class. I made this question in my mind.

Suppose $f(x)$ is a one-to-one function, and its definition is  $f(x)=max\left \{ x,3x\right \}=ax+b|x|+c$ find $a,b,c$

As I was teaching, I solved the question by two methods:

First, put three arbitrary numbers for $x$, for example, $x=0,1,2$ and solve the system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=0 &max \left \{ 0,0 \right \}=0 &a(0)+b(0)+c=0 \rightarrow c=0\\
 x=1&max \left \{ 1,3 \right \}=3  &a+b+c=3\\
 x=-1& max \left \{ -1,-3 \right \}=-1 & -a+b+c=-1
\end{matrix}\right.\\b=1 ,a=2\\ max\left \{ x,3x\right \}=2x+1|x|+0$$

Second, plot max{x,3x} and determine $a,b,c$ with respect to a figure of the function:

[image]

Obviously, $c=0$
$$\rightarrow a=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x>0 &  max\left \{ x,3x \right \}=3x&=ax+bx+0 \\
x<0 &  max\left \{ x,3x \right \}=x& =ax-bx+0
\end{matrix}\right.\\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\begin{Bmatrix}
(a+b)x=3x\\
(a-b)x=x
\end{Bmatrix}\rightarrow  a=2,b=1 \\\rightarrow max\left \{ x,3x \right \}=2x+|x|+0 $$

...and then, one of the students asked for a third method. I told her, "I will think, and you must think too!"

Now I have two questions:

1. What do you think about my handmade question?
2. Can you give me suggestion for more methods to solve it?

Comment: Tip from a teacher:  Please never use the word "obviously" when explaining.

Comment: One summer, I and some other high school teachers went to Reno to attend a math refresher class at the university.We asked the prof if there was anything he wanted us to do with our students so they would be better prepared for his classes. His answer was absolute values. We all laughed. I don't think there exists a high school math class that doesn't use absolute values somewhere. I still don't understand why students have such a hard time with them.

Comment: I was confused what you meant by the "absolute" function. I think you mean the "absolute value" function...

Comment: I made it abbreviation

Comment: " thumbtackthief " please tell me why " to not use -obviously- "!

Comment: @Khosrotash It makes people that didn't see this immediately, feel dumber than the rest.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the fact that, $\max\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$.

Therefore,  $\max\{x,3x\}=\frac{x+3x+|x-3x|}{2} = \frac{4x+|-2x|}{2} =2x+|x|$.

Comment: When I told this question ,I did not teach them $max\left \{ a,b \right \}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$  .Your hint is simple and nice ...also as clear as possible .thank you

Comment: I love second , third ,... solution for problems .Usually I can see the sense of loving mathematics ...in my student eyes ,when I tell another method to solve

Comment: @Khosrotash, unfortunately all that I ever see in my fellow mates when the teacher mentions another method is them dismissing one of the methods as 'bad' because of its difficulty level.

Comment: In my opinion, OP's problem could be a nice "introduction" to explain the nice representation of the maximum function given in this answer.

Comment: @Khosrotash You're welcome, I've always found interesting the relation between the  $\max$/$\min$ functions and the absolute value (the other relation being $|x|=\max\{x,-x\})$

Answer (score 14):

I will probably put more emphasis on those transformation properties
of the $\max(\cdot)$ function which is reasonably "obvious" and easy to
remember/use. For example,

1. $\max(a+b,a+c) = a + \max(b,c)$.
2. $\max(ab,ac) = a \max(b,c)$ when $a > 0$.
3. $\max(a,-a) = |a|$.

This may help a student to get familiar with such "tools" for attacking similar problems.
In any event, once a student knows about above properties, we have

$$\max(x,3x) = \max(2x - x,2x + x) \stackrel{(*1)}{=} 2x + \max(-x,x) \stackrel{(*3)}{=} 2x + |x|$$

Comment: $$max(a,−a)=|a|=a .sgn(a) =\sqrt{a^2}$$

Answer (score 7):

```
 max{x,3x} + min{x,3x} = 4x
 max{x,3x} - min{x,3x} = |2x|
 ----------------------------
 2max{x,3x} = 4x + 2|x|

 max{x,3x} = 2x + |x|


As a bonus, min{x,3x} = 2x - |x|
```

Comment: Do you read "yultan' answer  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes I did. He just used the result without showing how it was derived. I can never remember $\max\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$ but I do remember how to derive it.

Answer (score 4):

I like the question!  It is not immediately obvious to me, however, that it suffices to match your form to the given function at three points.  Perhaps that is the case, but if so it requires a separate argument.  Alternatively, having discovered the final form you could verify it directly.

I would address the original problem this way:  Your function, $f$, is $3x$ if $x ≥ 0$ and $x$ if $x < 0$.  We know functions that look like that!  $g(x) = x + |x|$, for example, is given by $2x$ if $x≥0$ and $0$ if $x<0$.  Ah, but that's just almost your function already.  All we have to do is add x.

Less formal than your method, clearly, but perhaps it has the advantage of drawing from a list of functions your students may already have looked at.  Anyway, it's an alternative!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(-x) = -ax + b|x|+ c$, thus breaking into symmetrical and anti symmetrical combinations one obtains 
$$
f(x) - f(-x) = 2ax\\
f(x) + f(-x) = 2b|x| + 2c
$$
Thus
$$
a = \frac{f(1) - f(-1)}{2} = \frac{3 + 1}{2} = 2\\
c = f(0) = 0\\
b = \frac{f(1) + f(-1)}{2} - c  = \frac{3 - 1}{2} = 1
$$

Second variation of the same idea:
$$
f(-x) = \max(-x, -3x) = -\min(x, 3x)
$$
so
$$
f(x) \pm f(-x) = \max(x, 3x) \mp \min(x, 3x)\\
f(x) + f(-x) = \max(x, 3x) - \min(x, 3x) = |x - 3x| = 2|x|\\
f(x) - f(-x) = \max(x, 3x) + \min(x, 3x) = x + 3x = 4x
$$
Comparing with
$$
f(x) - f(-x) = 2ax\\
f(x) + f(-x) = 2b|x| + 2c
$$
we get
$$
a = 2\quad b = 1\quad c = 0
$$

Comment: I don't get  , what's difference  between my first try and your solving !

Comment: because ,you use 3 points to find a,b,c at the last

Comment: @Khosrotash, I've updated my answer with evaluation-free solution

Comment: your main idea was "max(−x,−3x)=−min(x,3x)" ?